# What is the minimum length number the luhn algorithm will work on?

Tags: java, algorithm

Excluding the check digit, what is the minimum length number the luhn algorithm will work on?

My thoughts are that it would work on any number greater than 2 digits (again, excluding the check digit).

The reason I ask is this:
if i iterates over all digits in the number from right to left.
This causes i%2 == 0 (used to find alternate positions in the number) in my luhn validation to fail if the number is 3 digits or smaller (e.g. 125 -- which on paper seems to be a valid number)

Obviously I could change my condition from i%2== 0 to something else but if it's not the correct behavior for the algorithm it'd be nice to know.

Comment: What's wrong with i%2.  You start from the left digit and work your way down.

Comment: well if you have 125 the check digit would probably be 5. However using i%2 you do not get a valid number because it doubles the check digit instead of '2'.

Comment: Running the Luhn algorithm for 125, the 1 and the 5 get "doubled", and get 221 and the digits add to 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luhn's algorithm would work on two digits.  It will warn if a single digit is wrong and some (but not all) of the cases where digits are transposed.  Heck, it would theoretically work with one digit, but that's not very useful.  You can see for yourself by fixing one digit, then changing the other and verifying that each value of the other digit will give a unique "checksum".  With just two digits, however, just adding digits mod 10 would give you the same property, but it wouldn't catch any transposition errors.